# How do I run a script every day at 00:00 hrs to hit an django API on Ubuntu machine?

Tags: django, amazon-ec2

I need information about how to hit a django API running on ec2 on every night 00:00 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `crontab` to schedule running a `bash` file every midnight. The bash file will use `curl` to do a Django API call (or you can use anything else).

```
crontab -e
0 0 * * * /bin/sh django_api_call.sh
```

django_api_call.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

curl http://www.django-app.com
```